# Implement Salesforce Authentication (OAuth) in Xamarin Forms App

Tags: xamarin, salesforce, deep-linking

This article explains if anyone wants to integrate mobile app with Salesforce App and require to authenticate the app with salesforce OAuth

Answer (score 0):

iOS Implementation-

Step 1: To implement Deep Link define URL Schemes in info.plist according to connected app : The callback URL
[Defining URL Schemes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJYAo.png)

Step 2- Implement 'OpenUrl' method in AppDelegate to receive the deep link call in your app

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
    {
        var deepLinkURL = url;
        url = null;
        App myApp = App.Current as myApp.App;
        if (myApp != null && deepLinkURL != null)
        {
            LandingPage.DeepLinkURL = deepLinkURL;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Step 3- Now you have to check whether user is coming first time or already authenticated:

```
public async static Task HandleDeepLink()
    {
        //await SecureStorage.SetAsync(AppConstant.userId, "");
        /* Deep Link 
         * Check if user is same 
         * user is already loggedIn
         * Token expired
         */
        try
        {
            string data = DeepLinkURL.ToString();
            if (data.Contains("userId"))
            {
                // extract and save all the parameters
                userId = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(DeepLinkURL.Query).Get("userId");

                // if user not authenticated OR if different user
                isSameAsLastUser = await oAuth.ValidateUser(userId);
                if (isSameAsLastUser)
                {
                    // is already logged in
                    var isUserLoggedIn = await oAuth.IsUserLoggedIn();
                    if (isUserLoggedIn)
                    {
                        // navigate to scan
                        await SecureStorage.SetAsync(AppConstant.uniqueId, uniqueId);
                        Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Authentication());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // clear previous values in secure storage
                    AppConfig.SaveSFParameters("false");
                    Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Authentication());
                }
            }
            // Handle oAuth
            //Extract the Code
            else if (data.Contains("code"))
            {
                var code = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(DeepLinkURL.Query).Get("code");
                /*Exchange the code for an access token
                 * Save token 
                 * LoggedInTrue
                 */
                if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                {
                    var authInfo = await oAuth.GetAccessToken(code);
                    Console.WriteLine("auth token - " + authInfo.AccessToken);
                    oAuth.SaveAuthInfo(authInfo);
                    // save user info | set user logged in to true 
                    AppConfig.SaveSFParameters(userId,"true");
                    // retrieve all the parameters and pass here
                    Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage(userId));
                }
                else
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {
                        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(AppConstant.Alert, Resource.Resources.AlertMissingConnectivity, AppConstant.Ok);
                    });
                }
            }
            else if (data.Contains("error"))
            {
                var error = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(DeepLinkURL.Query).Get("error");

                //TODO: where the user should be redirected in case of OAuth error
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "There is some error while redirecting user to scan app, Please contact administrator", "Ok");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Authentication : ContentPage
{

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            var authUrl = Common.FormatAuthUrl(AppConfiguration.authEndPointURL,
            ResponseTypes.Code, AppConfiguration.clientId,
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(AppConfiguration.redirectUri));

            Browser.OpenAsync(new Uri(authUrl), BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
        }
}
}
```

Step 4 - Once user is authenticated successfully salesforce returns the authorization code

Step 5- Now you have to make salesforce API call to retrieve the access token by supplying the authorization code

Step 6- Once you receive the access toekn then save access token, refresh token in your app using 'Xamarin SecureStorage'

```
async public static void SaveAuthInfo(AuthToken authInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            await SecureStorage.SetAsync("oauth_token", authInfo.AccessToken);
            await SecureStorage.SetAsync("oauth_Id", authInfo.Id);
            await SecureStorage.SetAsync("oauth_InstanceUrl", authInfo.InstanceUrl);
            await SecureStorage.SetAsync("oauth_RefreshToken", authInfo.RefreshToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on device.
        }
    }
```

Step 7 - Now redirect user to landing page